# Regular expression, creating subpattern

Tags: php, regex

I have two strings that I have to extract data from. I use `preg_replace` to do this. However, I'm not sure how to make it so that the last `\s\:\:` can either match or not. I tried `{0,}`, but then it doesn't match the first string, and without it the last string doesn't match.

```
$strings = array(
    '13.02 - foobar1 bla bla :: 08.03.2013 - 23.12.2013',
    '06.05 21:00 - " foobar2 bla bla "',
)

foreach($strings as $data){
    $pattern = '/^(\d){2}\.(\d){2}\s?(\d){0,2}(\:)?(\d){0,2}\s\-(.*)(\s\:\:.*)?/i';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, '$6', $data);
}
```

I expect to get these two strings as the final output:

```
"foobar1 bla bla"
"" foobar2 bla bla ""
```

Comment: Your current code is working fine and matching both the strings. Check [this](http://codepad.org/h0ofNAuO). However, you are missing a `;` in the declaration of `$strings`.

Comment: For the first string, I need to remove ":: 08.03.2013 - 23.12.2013"  part

Comment: Making an example of input and the exact expected output would help a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like that:

```
$strings = array(
'13.02 - foobar1 bla bla :: 08.03.2013 - 23.12.2013',
'06.05 21:00 - " foobar2 bla bla "',
);

foreach($strings as $data){
$pattern = '/\d{2}\.\d{2}(?:\s\d{2}:\d{2})?\s-\s(.*?)(?:\s::|$).*/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $data) . "\r\n<br>";
}
```

It will output:

```
foobar1 bla bla 
" foobar2 bla bla "
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the syntax for the subpattern before.